# R functions to add italics, full y-axis, and p-value

Tags: r

[image]

I would like to italicize the label Abca4-/- ; add values on all of the bars of the y-axis ; and add a p-value comparing the two datasets. Here is the current code that I have written:

[image: Rcode]

I'm not sure what to try, but I only want to change the name of one of the groups to italics, not the entire x-axis label.

Comment: Adding pics is not a good way of sharing code-examples. Please add the texts.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You could try the following:

```r
pval <- t.test(`Area (nm^2)` ~ Type, data = mitochondria)$p.value

par(mar = c(5, 8, 5, 2))
boxplot(`Area (nm^2)` ~ Type, data = mitochondria, xlab = "", outpch = NA,
        xaxt = 'n', yaxt = 'n', ylab = "", main = 'Mitochondrial Area')
stripchart(`Area (nm^2)` ~ Type, data = mitochondria, vertical = TRUE, pch = 21, 
           add = TRUE, method = 'jitter', col = 'red', bg = 'yellow')
axis(1, at = 1:2, labels = c(expression(Wild-type), 
                             expression(italic(paste("Abca4 -/-")))))
axis(2, at = (2:8) * 100000, labels = paste0(2:8, '00,000'), las = 2)
text(1.5, 8e5, labels = paste('p =', round(pval, 3)))
title(ylab = expression(Area~(n*m^2)), line = 5)
```

[image]

---

**Data used**

Obviously, we don't have your data, so I had to construct a little data set with the same names and approximate characteristics to match your own data, inferred from the plot you included.

```r
set.seed(1)

mitochondria <- data.frame(`Area (nm^2)` = 1e5 + rnorm(200, 188, 10)^12 / 1e22,
                           Type = factor(rep(c('Wild-type', 'Abca4 -/-'), 
                                             each = 100),
                                         levels = c('Wild-type', 'Abca4 -/-')),
                           check.names = FALSE)
```

Comment: Hello @Allan  May I  request you to have a look at my question https://stackoverflow.com/questions/74308044/plotting-row-wise-correlation-of-data-frame-with-p-value